# Tag synonym inversion-of-control and ioc

Tags: discussion

I noticed that [inversion-of-control](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inversion-of-control) and [ioc](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ioc) are exactly about the same topic.  Moreover, the description of the [inversion-of-control](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inversion-of-control) even mentions IoC as abbreviation.

I tried to propose ioc as synonym for inversion-of-control but I could not because I have no score on neither of these tags.

Could someone create the synonym (or at least propose it), so the the topics can be merged, instead of remaining artificially split ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is done. The tag [ioc](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ioc) was made into a synonym of [inversion-of-control](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inversion-of-control) and merged into it.